# Is it possible to set the values of my Wix Burn gui with a registry search?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, themes

My WIX bootstrapper has various optional parameters as well as some settings the user sets up, such as the install location. I want these settings in the GUI to default to the previous values entered by the user when they go to the options screen of the Boostrapper. I have attempted to do this with a util:RegistrySearch of those settings (which are written by the MSI), but they do not appear to be reading in. Is there a way to do this?

These variables are the ones I am attempting to read the registry values into (each one corresponds to a GUI element in the Theme:

```
    <Variable Name="txtCustCode" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value=""/> <!--CUSTCODE-->
    <Variable Name="txtServer" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value=""/> <!--SERVER-->
    <Variable Name="txtDatabase" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value=""/> <!--DBNAME-->
```

These are the registry searches with which I am trying to read the values into the variables/controls

```
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="CustCode" Variable="txtCustCode" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Value="CustCode" Win64="no" Format="raw" Result="value" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="Server" Variable="txtServer" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\Server" Win64="no" Format="raw" Result="value"/>
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="Database" Variable="txtDatabase" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]\Database" Win64="no" Format="raw" Result="value" />
```

Comment: store the settings to a xml file the first installation , next time just deserialize and use same settings

Comment: I am not using a custom Bootstrapper at the moment - is something like this possible using built in functionality? The settings are already being written to INI files, but I was trying to use the registry since it looked like this might already work with the Wix Bootstrapper.

Comment: make 1 custom action on install initialize to read from reg , and 1 on install finalize to store

Comment: These need to be able to be configurable from the Bootstrapper GUI, which cannot run custom actions last time I checked. I was hoping to read in settings and fill the GUI with these settings, allowing the user to alter them if they need to.